# Scanner Regex Delimiter Issue

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, tokenize

I set a scanner's delimiter like:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(\\s*?)(#.*?\n)(\\s*?)");
```

The goal is to ignore comments of the form

```
#comment \n
```

Thus:

```
Hello#inline comment
world.
```

becomes:

```
Hello
world.
```

By setting the delimiter as I did, I would think:

```
Hello#inline comment world.
```

would become:

```
[Hello]
```

and:

```
Hello#inline comment\n world.
```

would become

```
[Hello, world.]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be mistaken but it looks like you may want to use something like

```
scanner.useDelimiter("#.*(\r?\n|\r)?");
```

You need to remember that not every line ends with `\n` (or `\r` or `\r\n`), for instance last lines can not have `\n` at its end. Also lime separators can be different in different operating systems.

Edit:

Based on your comments it looks like you may need to add Scanners standard delimiter (one or more whitespaces - `\\s+` or `\p{javaWhitespace}+` if you preffer), so try with

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*#.*(\r?\n|\r)?|\\s+");
```

Comment: This would work well if there was always a comment between tokens, but there isn't. Usually, there's just white space. "P3\n# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1\n10 10\n255" should become [P3, 10, 10, 255].